# Returning local unique_ptr as a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++14

I'm used to not use `std::move` when returning a `std::unique_ptr`, because doing so prohibits RVO. I have this case where I have a local `std::unique_ptr`, but the return type is a `std::shared_ptr`.
Here's a sample of the code:

```
shared_ptr<int> getInt1() {
    auto i = make_unique<int>();

    *i = 1;

    return i;
}

shared_ptr<int> getInt2() {
    return make_unique<int>(2);
}

unique_ptr<int> getInt3() {
    auto ptr = make_unique<int>(2);

    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    cout << *getInt1() << endl << *getInt2() << *getInt3() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC accepts both cases, but Clang refuses the `getInt1()` With this error:

```
main.cpp:10:13: error: no viable conversion from 'std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >' to 'shared_ptr<int>'
    return i;
           ^
```

Here's both cases on coliru: [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58b889ffc9495cec), [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ea02839b2557d57)

Both compiler accept the third case.

Which one is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that we'll be able to give better answers when we understand what you need this for. At the moment, this could trivially be solved by calling make_shared instead of make_unique. I assume there's some reason why that's not possible, and it would help to understand that reason.

Comment: @Elliott: What could be solved? He's not asking how to solve anything, he's asking if the code he has is correct by the standard.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct answer depends on which C++ standard you are talking about.

If we are talking about C++11, clang is correct (an explicit move is needed).  If we are talking about C++14, gcc is correct (an explicit move is not needed).

C++11 says in N3290/[class.copy]/p32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be
>   met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter,
>   and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload
>   resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed
>   as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If overload resolution
>   fails, ...

This demands that you only get the implicit move when the return expression has the same type as the function return type.

But [CWG 1579](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1579) changed this, and this defect report was accepted after C++11, and in time for C++14.  This same paragraph now reads:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but
>   not for an *exception-declaration*, and the object to be copied is
>   designated by an lvalue, or when the *expression* in a `return` statement
>   is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with
>   automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or
>   *lambda-expression*, overload resolution to select the constructor for
>   the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an
>   rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, ...

This modification basically allows the return expression type to be *convertible-to* the function return type and still be eligible for implicit move.

**Does this mean that the code needs a `#if`/`#else` based on the value of `__cplusplus`?**

One could do that, but I wouldn't bother.  If I were targeting C++14, I would just:

```
return i;
```

If the code is unexpectedly run under a C++11 compiler, you will be notified at compile-time of the error, and it is trivial to fix:

```
return std::move(i);
```

If you are just targeting C++11, use the `move`.

If you want to target both C++11 and C++14 (and beyond), use the `move`.  The downside of using `move` gratuitously is that you can inhibit RVO (Return Value Optimization).  However, in this case, RVO is not even legal (because of the conversion from the `return` statement to the return type of the function).  And so the gratuitous `move` does not hurt anything.

The one time you might lean towards a gratuitous `move` even when targeting C++14 is if without it, things still compile in C++11, and invoke an expensive *copy* conversion, as opposed to a *move* conversion.  In this case, accidentally compiling under C++11 would introduce a silent performance bug.  And when compiled under C++14 the gratuitous `move` still has no detrimental effects.

Comment: If you are using just C++11 I would encourage to create the correct type before returning rather than having "return std::move( ..." in your code. Because then the compiler might just do NRVO instead of moving a few times.

Answer (score 10):

`std::unique_ptr` could be used to construct `std::shared_ptr` only when it's a rvalue. See the constructor declaration of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

```
template< class Y, class Deleter >
shared_ptr( std::unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&& r );
```

So you need to use `std::move` to make the 1st case work, otherwise it should fail.

```
return std::move(i);
```

BTW: I compiled the code with [gcc 4.9.3](http://rextester.com/BNHC81313) it failed either.

```
source_file.cpp:14:12: error: cannot bind ‘std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >’ 
lvalue to ‘std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&&’
     return i;
            ^
```

Comment: Hi, could you change your answer to specify that the move is needed only for `c++11`?